# What is the `target` in javascript decorators

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, decorator, babeljs

I'm playing with javascript decorators but I'm having a hard time with the **target** which is passed to the decorator function

For example, if you have

```
@Bar()
class Foo {
    @deprecated(true)
    doMagic() {}
}

function Bar() {
    return function decorator(target) {

    }
}

function deprecated(state) {
    return function decorator(target, name, config) {
         return config;
    }
}
```

I would expect that both **target**s are one and the same thing, right, well it isn't.  For example

```
function Bar() {
    return function decorator(target) {
        let bar = new target(); // WORKS
        bar instanceof target; // -> true
    }
}

function deprecated(state) {
    return function decorator(target, name, config) {
         let bar = new target(); // ERROR
         let bar = new target.constructor() // WORKS

         bar instanceof target; // ‌TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
         bar instanceof target.constructor // WORKS
         return config;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a difference between both **target**s, and my question is what is wrong with that second ***target***

I use node v7.8.0 and I'm using the follow babel plugins (.babelrc)

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
       "stage-0"
   ]
```

}

Comment: Decorators aren't part of ECMAScript standard now and current stage is 2.
https://github.com/tc39/proposals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the old legacy decorators. Beware that the [decorators proposal](http://tc39.github.io/proposal-decorators/) has moved on since then and the API is still evolving. The proposal is (as I write this) at Stage 2, e.g. "draft" (see [this document](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/) for details).

The `target` in your `@deprecated` decorator using the old legacy plugin is the object that will ultimately be saved as `Foo.prototype`. Whereas in `@Bar`, it's the `Foo` class constructor itself. That's why in your `@deprecated` decorator, you can't use `new target` (`target` is a non-callable object), but you can use `new target.constructor` (which is `Object`).

But again: This stuff is still in flux.